# Unable to connect to 3rd party ODBC driver in Go with alexbrainman/odbc on Linux

Tags: ubuntu, go, odbc, cdata-drivers

I'm attempting to connect to a data source with a 3rd party ODBC driver (downloadable [here](http://www.cdata.com/drivers/redis/download/odbc)) in Go using the [alexbrainman ODBC driver](https://github.com/alexbrainman/odbc). I've tested the DSN in question using:

```
isql -v "CData Redis Source"
```

Everything works as expected there. And I know that I have unixODBC 2.3.1 installed (`isql --version`).

## The Problem

When I try to run the following Go program, I get this error message, spawned from the `db.Ping()` call (which Google translate seems unable to translate):

> SQLDriverConnect: {㄰こ0} [unixODBC]湉慶楬⁤潣湮捥楴湯猠牴湩⁧祳瑮硡愠⁴湩敤⁸ㅛ㩝

My code:

```
package main

import (
  _ "github.com/alexbrainman/odbc"
  "database/sql"
  "log"
)

func main() {
  db, err := sql.Open("odbc","DSN=CData Redis Source")
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err);
  }
  
  var (
    name string
  )
  
  rows, err := db.Ping()
  if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
}
```

I see the same error if I do a `db.Query()` or a `db.Prepare()`.

## The Details

- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- unixODBC 2.3.1
- CData Software ODBC Driver for Redis
- go1.6.2 linux/amd64
- github.com/alexbrainman/odbc

## The Request

I'd be happy with a translation of the error message to help me debug AND/OR some help in determining why my error message is not in English AND/OR an actual proposed solution to the error message.

Comment: trying moving this import: `_ "github.com/alexbrainman/odbc"` after the standard one: `"database/sql"`

Comment: I tried swapping the imports, no luck. Thanks @YandryPozo

Comment: It looks to me more like an issue with unixODBC and/or CData driver. Check your DSN with isql. Try to actually connect and query some data. Once unixODBC and below are sorted out, the go side should generally work without issues. I would also suspect that cryptic error message is ascii interpreted as utf-16 or something like that.

Comment: If isql works, but go code still doesn't. You can also try checking what odbc libraries your go binary is linked against and compare it to isql.

Comment: isql definitely works. I'll look into the linked libraries. Thanks, @Seva

Comment: @Seva, I've compared the linked libraries and they are the same, any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to ensure that the CData Driver was configured to use UTF-16 encoding, as is required by unixODBC. To do so, I edited the driver's INI file:

*/opt/cdata/cdata-odbc-driver-for-redis/lib/cdata.odbc.redis.ini*

```
[Driver]
DriverManagerEncoding = UTF-16
```

Once this was done the CData driver worked with the alexbrainman/odbc database driver (and other Go-related ODBC database drivers) as expected.